# wkhtmktopdf on shared hosting does not return any data...?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

Hi friends currently i m working on a small business project.

for this project i need to convert my dynamic html page into a PDF file..

I googled for html to pdf and found wkhtml...
in my local-host system its works like charm..

But in my shared server it does not gives any output... errors also. when php wrap execute, it fails silently..

Any idea guys??

another thing.. In my shared hosting, they are disabled exec,proc_open and other process related functions, So i used .htaccess file to point another php.ini for reconfiguring the disabled_functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your hosting provider has disabled the exec methods, I'm sure they won't be pleased to find out you're trying to use wkhtmltopdf. It might be a good idea to contact them about your plans.

When downloading wkhtmltopdf, make sure you grab the right package (based on the server specs). Your best bet is to use one of the static packages as it provides most of the libraries needed to run wkhtmltopdf. You might also need to change the file permissions to be able to execute the file.

Lastly, make sure your custom php.ini is even used by php (calling phpinfo() will do the trick).